# How to use "every" pattern operator in Flink CEP

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep

In Esper CEP engine event patterns, there's `Every` operator which indicates that the pattern sub-expression should restart when the sub-expression qualified by the every keyword evaluates to true or false.

[According to this document](http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.5.0/esper-reference/html/event_patterns.html#pattern-logical-every), We can use `every` operator in different ways like:

```
    A -> B
    every ( A -> B )
    every A -> B
    A -> every B
    every A -> every B
```

I would like to know which of these patterns are possible in Flink CEP? I want to use `every A -> B` in Flink but don't know how.

And which one of the above patterns this default CEP pattern in Flink represents? (Using Flink v1.1.4)

```
Pattern<Event, ?> pattern = Pattern.begin("start").where(evt -> evt.getId() == 42)
    .followedBy("end").where(evt -> evt.getName().equals("end"));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink provides some [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/libs/cep.html#conditions) as to how to use every which says that if you specify subtype then it will be called for every iteration

```
start.subtype(SubEvent.class).where(new SimpleCondition<SubEvent>() {
    @Override
    public boolean filter(SubEvent value) {
        return ... // some condition
    }
});
```

But in my opinion, it is not what you are looking for. However, you can have a look at a light-weight [Siddhi- Flink CEP library](https://github.com/haoch/flink-siddhi) by using which you will be able to use siddhi query language in Flink